# how to continue after NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, exception

i'm trying to get all href with find_element_by_class_name("picture")
but i'm stuck after a while in NoSuchElementException and the the selenium stuck

i have added try/ except, but it seems that it doesn't work

```
for link in url_list:
 try:
    Mydriver.get(link)
    product = Mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    for pr in product:
        if ("reseller.c-data.co.il" not in link):
            continue
        else:
            if (Mydriver.find_element_by_class_name("product-title")):
                product_link = pr.get_attribute("href")
                product_list.append(product_link)
                print(product_link)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print ("erron on url :", product_link)
    continue
```

i want the selenium will continue and the code will move to the next link in the url_list. 
but all i'm getting is " selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".picture"} "

what to do ?

Comment: Where is the NSEE error occuring? It seems to me that the error may be on the print link if the NSEE error occurs before product_link is defined, making it so you never hit the continue statement.

Comment: try changing `if (Mydriver.find_element_by_class_name("product-title"))`  to `if (Mydriver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-title") > 0)`  notice the `s` in `elements`

Comment: My hunch is your try & catch are in the wrong place, but tough to tell with that error message as it doesn't seem to match up with your code snippet. Where is the selector of .picture coming from?

Comment: @DMart - so where to put the try/except ? the error happanes when the selenium get to the url [link] (https://www.facebook.com/ComputerCDATA/)

Comment: @DvirYadae is the `if ("reseller.c-data.co.il" not in link):` in this usecase? What are you trying to do through that?

Comment: please add the error message your seeing in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you provided, I think you can combine your different filters and avoid the problem altogether. You are looking for `A` tags with an href attribute... then checking to see if the href contains "reseller.c-data.co.il" and then searching for a child element that has a class name "product-title". You can do all of this with a CSS selector

```
for link in url_list:
    Mydriver.get(link)
    for pr in Mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='reseller.c-data.co.il'] .product-title"):
        product_link = pr.get_attribute("href")
        product_list.append(product_link)
        print(product_link)
```

You can also use an XPath: `//a[contains(@href,'reseller.c-data.co.il')]//*[@class='product-title']`. I prefer CSS selectors because they are faster, better supported in different browsers, and the syntax is simpler.

CSS selector references

[W3C spec Selectors Overview](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)
[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Comment: no - doesnt help . im still getting error  :      elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".picture"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: @Dev - i have tried what youv'e wrote - it doesnt help . i'm still get that error : "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".picture"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)"

Comment: There's nothing in my code that has `.picture` as a CSS selector. The error is referring to some other code.